# How to upload one excel with multiple worksheet using php or cakephp

Tags: php, excel

I would like to ask how I can upload one excel workbook with multiple worksheets into a database. How can I read the 5 worksheet's names, which are *office table*, *office chairs*, *aircon*, *electric fan*, and *filling cabinet*.

They also have a different format. I only upload the asset number, asset description, no of unit, and location to the database .

[image: office table]

[image: office chairs]

[image: aircon]

[image: electric fan]

[image: filling cabinet]

Here is my current code:

```
$file1 = $this->data['Data']['file']['tmp_name'];
$file = fopen($file1, "r");
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    var_dump($emapData);

    exit;
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: `How can read the 5 worksheet`, umm, just for clarification, you are uploading 5 different csv files? or an Office document (Open, Libre, Microsoft)? well, did you ask *how to upload 5 files and store it in the database*?

Comment: i just uploading 1 excel file name assets.xlsx with multiple worksheet/spreadsheet.. the 5 tables are the worksheet/spreadsheet sir..

Comment: well, the reason your code *won't* work is.. [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), it's only for csv.. for another format, you'll need another library.. anyway, explain your file format in the question to help someone else to help you..

Comment: ah.. sorry sir if my english and explanation too bad... using PHPEXCEL my question could be done?

Comment: it is **possible** but sadly, i can't give you an example, you should try [this to load the xlsx file](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/03-Loading-a-Spreadsheet.md) instead of `fgetcsv`..